# Node js response.end

Tags: node.js

I have a little problem with that ...

```
 var server = http.createServer(function (req, res, data) {
    var url = 'http://localhost:11918/api/log';

    http.get(url, function (res) {
        var body = '';
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function () {
            var data = JSON.parse(body);           
            Data.emit('JsData', data);
        });
    }).on('error', function (e) {
        console.log("Got an error: ", e);
    });    

    Data.on('JsData', function (message) {
        res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
        res.write(JSON.stringify(message));
        res.end();
    });
});
```

Error: write after end

it 's nice but it is possible to rewrite several times on the server .... ?
and how ?

Comment: First hello and then thank you ^^

Comment: there is a **res** parameter conflict, try to change the `http.get` parameters

Comment: 'Data' is no where defined in your example?

Answer (score 0):

I use that .... and it work :

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var request = require('request');
var EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;
var Data = new EventEmitter();


var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    var url = 'http://localhost:11918/api/log';   
    http.get(url, function (res) {
        var body = '';
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function () {
            var data = JSON.parse(body);           
            Data.emit('JsData', data);
        });
    }).on('error', function (e) {
        console.log("Got an error: ", e);
    });    
        Data.on('JsData', function (message) {                              
        res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" });     
        res.end(JSON.stringify(message));
    });

});
```

but I do not know if this is the best method